# Publish-Subscribe Channels Both Going to Kafka Result in Duplicate KafkaProducerContexts

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am attempting to use Spring Integration to send data from one channel to two different Kafka queues after those same data go through different transformations on the way to their respective queues. The problem is I apparently have duplicate producer contexts, and I don't know why.

Here is my flow configuration:

```
flow -> flow
        .channel(“firstChannel")
        .publishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), s -> s
                .subscribe(f -> f
                                .transform(firstTransformer::transform)
                                .channel(MessageChannels.queue(50))
                                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaConfig)
                                        .addProducer(firstMetadata(), brokerAddress), e -> e.id(“firstKafkaOutboundChannelAdapter")
                                        .autoStartup(true)
                                        .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).receiveTimeout(0).taskExecutor(taskExecutor))
                                        .get())
                )
                .subscribe(f -> f
                                .transform(secondTransformer::transform)
                                .channel(MessageChannels.queue(50))
                                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaConfig)
                                        .addProducer(secondMetadata(), brokerAddress), e -> e.id(“secondKafkaOutboundChannelAdapter")
                                        .autoStartup(true)
                                        .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).receiveTimeout(0).taskExecutor(taskExecutor))
                                        .get())
                ));
```

The exception is this:

*Could not register object [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext@3163987e] under bean name 'not_specified': there is already object [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext@15f193b8] bound*

I have tried using different `kafkaConfig` objects, but that hasn't helped. Meanwhile, the `ProducerMetadata` instances are distinct as you can see from the different first parameters to `addProducer`. Those provide the names of the respective destination queues among other metadata.

It sounds like there are some implicit bean definitions that are being created that conflict with each other.

How can I resolve this exception with the two `KafkaProducerContext`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not to use `.get()` on those `KafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec` and let Framework to work out the environment for you.

The issue is because `KafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec implements ComponentsRegistration` and no body cares about the:

```
public Collection<Object> getComponentsToRegister() {
    this.kafkaProducerContext.setProducerConfigurations(this.producerConfigurations);
    return Collections.<Object>singleton(this.kafkaProducerContext);
}
```

after manual `.get()` invocation.

I agree, this a some inconvenience and we should find some better solution for end-application, but there is no yet choice, unless follow with the `Spec` style for the Framework components, like `Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter()`.

Hope I am clear.

**UPDATE**

OK, it's definitely an issue on our side. And we will fix it soon: 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-216
https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-217

Meanwhile the workaround for you is like this:

```
 KafkaProducerContext kafkaProducerContext = (KafkaProducerContext) kafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec.getComponentsToRegister().iterator().next();
 kafkaProducerContext.setBeanName(null);
```

Where you should move

```
Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaConfig)
                                    .addProducer(firstMetadata(), brokerAddress)
```

to the separate `private` method to get access to that `kafkaProducerContext`.

Comment: I got rid of the manual `.get()` invocations, but the error remains the same.

Comment: OK. Testing that locally... Thank you for catching anyway!

Comment: No problem. This is kind of a big deal for me, so any snapshots to pull or any workarounds are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The workaround worked for me. Thanks. Please let me know when the fix is in and how to obtain it--either in this thread or through any of the ways on my profile page on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The fix is already pushed to the `1.1.2` version. But yes, you should use `https://repo.spring.io/snapshot` repo to pick up `BUILD-SNAPSHOT` artifacts.